# Laravel : Command bus not going asynchronous

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I'm using Laravel 5.1's Command bus to run a specific task (upload a file, validate then record it in my db) on a background process.

I tried uploading small csv file like 1.4kb (40 rows) and it worked.

When when i tried uploading a 1MB csv file (20000 rows), I noticed it is not running in background process. It waits for the job to be finished and then loads the correct page which is not the way I wanted it :(.

I think I followed the Laravel documentation on how to run a command bus in asynchronous process just by php artisan make:command PurchasePodcast --queued.

[**Reference**](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/bus)

My code :

```
class ImportPricelistCommand extends Command implements SelfHandling, ShouldQueue
{
    use InteractsWithQueue, SerializesModels;
```

Am i missing something? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel 5.1 the command bus is replace by jobs. You are using Laravel 5.1 and following 5.0 documentation.

Answer (score 0):

The command bus was renamed [jobs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queues) in Laravel 5.1, and the “command” stuff left to not break 5.0 applications. Jobs can be dispatched asynchronously as well as queued to be processed asynchronously.

Basically, you want to remove the `ShouldQueue` interface and `InteractsWithQueue` trait from your command/job class. As you may have gathered, this tells the dispatcher to queue them rather than process them synchronously.

Comment: it didnt work. I removed the ShouldQueue. It still wait for the page to finish before it can go to the next page. Do I need to use the queue feature in laravel to achieve what i want? http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queues. Basically I just want my command bus to run asynchronously.

Comment: I thought that's what you wanted? If not, re-add the interface and trait, and have you changed the queue driver in your .env file to something other than `sync`?